# Twitter Codebird Webhook Registration Not Working

Tags: php, api, twitter, codebird

Actually I want to register a webhook for Twitter.For this purpose I'm using codebird.But while trying to register the webhook and the response as "httpstatus : 403"

```
$url        = 'https://<domain>/webhook/twitter_webhook';
$params     = ['url'=>$url,'env_name' =>'<TITLE>'];
$response   = $this->api->accountActivity_all_ENV_NAME_webhooks($params);
```

Error Response

---

```
  {#1001 
      +"errors": array:1 [
      0 => {#1004
      +"code": 200
      +"message": "Forbidden."
     }
    ]
   +"httpstatus": 403
   +"rate": null
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is a bug in this package. please check https://github.com/jublo/codebird-php/issues/244.

Please Try using https://twitteroauth.com/

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any another solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you please re-test with the revision [f2265fc](https://github.com/jublo/codebird-php/commit/f2265fcfc592798b9a2998d2d5879d108acc4aaf). I have recently added support for the account activity API to Codebird …